# Is it possible to make my firefox extension gain focus over other programs?

Tags: javascript, firefox, window, focus

I am developing a firefox extension that I need to gain focus over other programs. window.focus() works only over other firefox windows. Is this possible?

Comment: The longer answer is Yes :-) Depends how much effort you want to go to, and how many platforms you want to support.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to another question I answered here: [xul:panel position on multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070456/xulpanel-position-on-multiple-monitors)

I was able to achieve what you want with the help of an external DLL loaded/used by js-ctypes. In order to manipulate OS-level window focus, you'll need to be able to do two things:

- *find* the Firefox window in question (`find_window` javascript function below), and
- focus the window (`window_focus` function below).

I found the easiest way to find a window handle was to change the window title to something predicable that won't clash with other window titles (say a MD5 sum of `"your-app"+(new Date())`), then to enumerate all OS-level windows looking for the window with that title (`find_window`).

Once you have a window handle, you can call `window_focus` (defined below) to focus the OS-level window.

---

Example for Win32:

Here are the basics for binding the external DLL to JavaScript. This example only covers Win32, but the same process applies for each.

There are 3 parts:

- The privileged JavaScript code to load/bind the platform specific (i.e: Win32) APIs
- The CPP header file for our external DLL
- The CPP source file for our external DLL

I build a simple GUI DLL project in VS2010 with the later two files & compiled wmctrl.dll, depending on msvcr100.dll, and used Dependency Walker to find the "plain C" symbols exported by the DLL for use by js-ctypes.

In privileged JavaScript code (e.g: in your addon code):

```
// import js-ctypes 
const {Cc,Ci,Cu} = require("chrome"); // you probably don't need this line.
var file=null, lib=null, ctypes = {};
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm", ctypes);
var ctypes = ctypes.ctypes;

// build platform specific library path (yours will be named/located differently)
var filename = ctypes.libraryName("wmctrl");
var comp = "@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"; // read the docs for this!!!
var file = Cc[comp].getService(Ci.nsIProperties).get("CurProcD", Ci.nsIFile); 
file.append("browser_code"); // a sub-folder
file.append(filename);

// get the JavaScript library interface (load the library)
var lib = ctypes.open(file.path);

// wmctrl_find_window: returing unsigned 32bit (long) "window handle"
// takes string "window title".
var find_window = lib.declare("?wmctrl_find_window@@YAKPAD@Z", 
    ctypes.stdcall_abi, ctypes.uint32_t,
    ctypes.char.ptr);

// wmctrl_window_focus: takes unsigned 32bit (long) "window handle".
var window_focus = lib.declare("?wmctrl_window_focus@@YAXK@Z", 
    ctypes.stdcall_abi, ctypes.void_t,
    ctypes.uint32_t);
```

wmctrldll.h

```
#ifdef WMCTRLDLL_EXPORTS
#define WMCTRLDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define WMCTRLDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

WMCTRLDLL_API unsigned long wmctrl_find_window(char* find_title);
WMCTRLDLL_API void wmctrl_window_focus (unsigned long wid);
```

wmctrldll.cpp

```
typedef struct {
  HWND hWnd;
  char title[255];
} myWinSpec;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) {
  char String[255];
  myWinSpec* to_find = (myWinSpec*) lParam;

  // not a window
  if (!hWnd) return TRUE;                                      

  // not visible
  if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return TRUE;

  // no window title                     
  if (!GetWindowTextA(hWnd, (LPSTR)String, 255)) return TRUE;  

  // no title match
  if (strcmp(String, to_find->title) != 0) return TRUE;        

  to_find->hWnd = hWnd;
  return FALSE;
}

WMCTRLDLL_API void wmctrl_window_focus(unsigned long wid) {
  SetForegroundWindow((HWND) wid);
}

WMCTRLDLL_API unsigned long wmctrl_find_window(char* find_title) {
  myWinSpec to_find;

  sprintf_s(to_find.title, sizeof(to_find.title), "%s", find_title);
  to_find.hWnd = 0;

  EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM)&to_find);
  return (unsigned long) to_find.hWnd;
}
```

I also did this for Linux (X11) and Mac OS X without too much difficulty.